# Passing value from the server to the client in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I would like to create a composable, that increments a global counter and returns the incremented value every time it is called.
It needs to be SSR safe.

I made this:

```js
// composables/useId.ts
let id = 0

export default function () {
    if (id >= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) id = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
    const incrementedId = id++
    return useState(() => incrementedId)
}
```

Example use in the `<template>`:

```js
<ul>
    <li v-for="_ in 10">
        ID is: {{ useId() }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that every element has the same ID value.
I assume this is because the `useState()` composable generates a key based on the line and file it's used in (in this case `useId.ts`) and this key is used to retrieve the data on the client - which is the same for every function call.

How could I fix this?

---

*I'd like to use this composable to guarantee a unique value for HTML ids*

*example:*

```js
// parent component
<template>
    <MyInput v-for="_ in 10" />
</template>

// ---------------------------------------------

// MyInput.vue
<template>
    <label :for="generatedId">
        Something
    </label>

    <input type="text" :id="generatedId">
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const generatedId = useId()
</script>
```

Comment: Found a solution for this ?

Comment: Vue 3.5 is going to introduce a composable called `useId()` which will solve this problem. Also, Nuxt 3.10 introduced a composable with the same name as a temporary solution until it is implemented in Vue.